# Requirement to capture data from a button click in the email

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am new to SFMC and I have a requirement. We need to send an email to users from SFMC and the same will have  three details specified

First Name
Last  Name
Email
Login

If these details are correct users needs to click on  a button and  on the button click these details should be captured in  data extension , or at least the email id and we should be able to identify which button got clicked

There is a similar  button  Not correct  and if it is not correct then user should have  get a provision to enter the correct details and those details also  we should capture  Could you please let me know how this can be achieved ?
[image]

Comment: Can  I get some pointers on how to enter the data in DE up on Submit ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you simply need to leverage the [_Click Dataview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5) for clicks engagement. If you are using a cloudpage to update the data you could insert the data into a DE upon submit, If this is an external site, you would need to make an api call to insert the data into a DE

Comment: So far this is the best answer, but even if they don't have CloudPages this can still be done. They could put a unique Alias on each link, then query for that alias into a data extension.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Can you please let me know how to insert the data in DE up on Submit ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sending this email in a Journey. So that, using the Engagement Split activity based on clicks, you will be able to create two paths ('Yes' and 'No') in which you can update a value in a Data Extension to flag the answer using the Update Contact activity.